# node running in docker send req from outside container, getting as Empty reply from server

Tags: node.js, docker

when sending req as curl:0.0.0.0:8000

getting as 'welcome'

but when sending as curl:0.0.0.0:8000/v1/subjects
getting as Empty reply from server

Comment: Is your node application serving other requests? By the way, your image is not visible.

Comment: Do a `curl -v` and also check your nodejs logs to see what is happening

Comment: Could you provide a source code?

Comment: yes, im build and run docker as 

docker build -t myapp .  and 

docker run -d --name hello -p 8000:8000 myapp 

and then execute as curl -v 0.0.0.0:8000  
getting 'welcome my app' and 200 ok

but when im execute as   

curl -v 0.0.0.0:8000/v1/subjects 
getting Empty message from server....!!

im giving in my server.js as 
app.listen(8000, "0.0.0.0");